# How to install Firefox 3.6 and 4.0+ in parallel?

Tags: firefox, versions

Up until last week, I had both Firefox 3.6 and Firefox 4.0 installed, which was good for testing web applications.

But now the nightly channel contains Firefox 6 instead of Firefox 4. I tried using the stable channel, but that replaced Firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*in the answer below, "Firefox 3.6" is the installed version, "Firefox 4" is another version you want to use*

The Firefox package from Mozilla can be extracted to any directory, like `/opt` or your home directory. I'm using separate profiles for Firefox 3.6 and 4 for optimal compatibility.

1. Download Firefox from [mozilla.com](http://www.mozilla.com/nl/firefox/) to your home directory. (note that these packages are built for 32-bit systems, 64-bit systems may encounter strange issues like missing icons)
2. [Open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) and extract the archive to `~/firefox` by running:

   ```
   tar xjf firefox-4.0.tar.bz2
   ```

   (replace the filename accordingly)
3. Create the directory `~/bin` if non-existent and make a link named `firefox4` to the Firefox 4 executable:

   ```
   mkdir ~/bin
   ln -s ~/firefox/firefox ~/bin/firefox4
   ```

   If you `~/bin` was previously non-existent, you need to re-login to update your the path in which Ubuntu searches for applications. From now on, you can run Firefox 4 by executing `firefox4`. If you wish to use Firefox 4 instead of the Firefox version installed on the system, run:

   ```
   ln -s ~/bin/firefox ~/bin/firefox4
   ```

**Important**: if you download Firefox from Mozilla, the auto-update feature of Firefox is enabled. The package manager (`apt`) does not take care of updating the Firefox package from Mozilla. To check for updates manually, go to *Help* => *Check for updates*.

Optional steps if you'd like to run Firefox 3.6 and 4 simultaneously with a single command:

1. Create new profile for Firefox 4 by starting the Profile Manager:

   ```
   firefox4 -ProfileManager
   ```
2. Press `Create Profile` and enter `firefox4` as profile name. Press Finish when done.
3. Create the file `~/bin/fx4`, containing:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   firefox4 --no-remote -P firefox4 "$@"
   ```
4. Create the file `~/bin/fx`, containing:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   firefox --no-remote -P default "$@"
   ```

   (replace `default` by your profile name for Firefox 3.6)
   It's assumed that the Firefox executable is Firefox 3.6 which is the case on Maverick (10.10), but not Natty (11.04).
5. Make it executable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/bin/fx4 ~/bin/fx
   ```
6. From now on, you can run the Firefox 4 profile by executing `fx4` and Firefox 3.6 by running `fx`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did for checking out firefox 4 along with pre-installed firefox 3.6 in ubuntu 10.10. You can run only one version at a time and some extensions may not work.

- [Download](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/products/download.html?product=firefox-4.0&os=linux&lang=en-US) firefox4
- extract it somewhere with file-roller or you can
  use `tar` command
- create a symlink in system path

  `sudo ln -s /path/to/firefox4/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox4`
- run firefox with `firefox4` command
  from terminal or you can create a
  launcher on the panel as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you [download](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) the packages of firefox 4 or later, you can extract the folder, and run the script in the folder named firefox: firefox  will open up, with your addons, setting, and bookmarks in place.

NOTE: but in this way the two browsers cannot be used at the same time: one has to be closed (check task manager) for the other to start.

---

To be able to start both at the same time and to avoid searching for compatibility with addons and so on, you might consider using **modified versions** of Mozilla Firefox ('[clones](https://askubuntu.com/q/228309/47206)', re-branded browsers) that do not interfere with each other, like **Icecat** instead of Firefox 4+ (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuzilla-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install icecat -y`) or (if you want to have latest Firefox) **[Swiftweasel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swiftweasel/files/Swiftweasel%20Trunk%20%28Unstable%29/3.5%20RC3%20%28tar.gz%29/)** instead of Firefox 3.6.