# Firefox 3.6 in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Firefox 3.6 and 4.0 in parallel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35715/how-to-install-firefox-3-6-and-4-0-in-parallel)

Is there any way to install Firefox 3.6 in Ubuntu 11.04? I need Firefox 3.6 because Firefox 4 does not support Google Gears which is required for Offline Gmail and Google explicitly stated that they are not going to update Gears for Firefox 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it from [Mozilla site](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/), extract the **tar.bz2** file somewhere in your home and execute the *firefox* file inside it. See [my tutorial](http://www.webgapps.org/firefox/installing-other-versions) for step-by-step instructions.

I would recommend using a separate profile for the 3.6 account. You can use the [Mozilla's Profile Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Profile_Manager) to create profiles and start different versions of Firefox.