# How do I install Firefox 3.6?

Tags: 11.04, installation, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Firefox 3.6 and 4.0 in parallel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35715/how-to-install-firefox-3-6-and-4-0-in-parallel)

I need to install Firefox 3.6 for plugin compatibility on Ubuntu 11, how do I install Firefox 3.6 so that it replaces the default Firefox install with this one?

Answer (score 3):

1. **Uninstall Firefox 4 from the software Center.**
2. **Download Firefox from  [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all-older.html) and install it**.

   See this [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35715/how-to-install-firefox-3-6-and-4-0-in-parallel) and this [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38708/firefox-3-6-in-ubuntu-11-04) for installation.
3. **If you want you can lock the current version of Firefox by going to `Synaptic`** :

[image]

So you will not get notified of an upgrade in the update manager of a newer version of Firefox.

Comment: Sorry, where do I find the .deb file?

Comment: Sorry There is no .deb file. See this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38708/firefox-3-6-in-ubuntu-11-04).

Comment: And this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35715/how-to-install-firefox-3-6-and-4-0-in-parallel) may help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need install firefox on linux, just download it at http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all-older.html, untar it, and then run 'firefox' file.

But if you don't want FF3.6 change your FF4's settings, you can follow this guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Profile_Manager

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all-older.html
download the linux versoin an tar it and install it and mark that you don't want to upgrade it. if want to use 5 and 3.6 you should have a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Profile_Manager.

Comment: I've downloaded the old tar, how do I install it?

Comment: it is not the best install ever but have a look at http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Installing%20Firefox%20on%20Linux

Answer (score 0):

You can try uninstalling Firefox 4, then reinstalling Firefox 3.6. You would have to open up the Package Manager (I'm really hazy about what programs are available on Ubuntu), and find Firefox installed, unclick it. That would uninstall it.