# apt-get install firefox-3.6 installs 5.0

Tags: firefox

As title says, I'm trying to install firefox 3.6. However, I have no luck with achieving that.

I tried

> apt-get install firefox-3.6

and after installation in `about:` there is "Firefox 5.0"

How can I force 3.6 to install ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/50369/how-do-i-install-firefox-3-6/50373#comment-56008

Comment: it isn't. Because 5.0 IS INSTALLED, not 3.6 by this tutorial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firefox 3.6 is only available in Lucid and Maverick repositories. If you are using Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal, then Firefox 5 is what you get.

You could download Firefox 3.6 from Mozilla and run it from you home or /opt, but if you provide more info about why you want to downgrade, then maybe we can help. Firefox 3.6 support won't last long. Besides, it is much slower than Firefox 5.

Comment: reason: http://superuser.com/questions/301841/force-firefox-to-install-add-on

Comment: I do use Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS
because I had internet problems on 11.04 (system releated, not connection)

Comment: Do you have any ppa for Firefox installed? I can't think of a reason for Firefox 5 being installed, unless you have a ppa that provides that version, since it is not in Lucid official repos. So, you need to disable the ppa, update and install firefox again. BTW, just use sudo apt-get firefox. No need to add the 3.6 to the command.

Comment: I used this command before `add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa`
However, if I wasn't using "-3.16", it will AUTOMATICALLY install the latest version

Comment: Also, it seems Firesheep is not supported on Linux.

Comment: wow, some reference ?

Comment: It works fine to this guy http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7CPgXiODzo

Comment: After reading what Firesheep does, I don't think it would be approved by Mozilla to be hosted on AMO. You might even get into legal trouble, since the add-on allows to log to web sites with other users cookies. For that reason, I will refrain from helping you any further. Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep

Comment: The reference you asked for: http://codebutler.github.com/firesheep/

Comment: There are also people which does not abuse these apps and I want to try it on my OWN application on my OWN PC and NB. I am aware of these bad things

Comment: In the YouTube video, the guy is using Chrome, not Firefox. Anyway, you need to disable or remove the mozilla-daily ppa and reinstall firefox package. I haven't tested mozilla-daily recently, but they changed some things and it is using firefox-trunk for the latest nightly builds. I presume the regular firefox package is being updated to Firefox 5, which is the latest stable.

Comment: BTW, if you just need for testing, download Firefox 3.6 from Mozilla and install it in your home or opt directory. You can also use my FoxTester add-on, which allows to test multiple versions with just a few clicks. See https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxtester/

Comment: I tried to download 3.6 package from official source, but it ALWAYS showed me that I have 5.0 installed! But thanks for link !

Comment: I have a tutorial on how to install manually downloaded Firefox, but my site is down right now. What you need is to extract it to your home, then start Firefox via command-line like ~/firefox/firefox, assuming you extracted  to your home. BTW, Firefox 5 needs to be closed first.

Comment: It looks like foxtester doesnt work for me :( I can't click on that icon

Comment: Then disable mozilla-daily and reinstall firefox.

Comment: How can I disable that? :/

Comment: Open "System >> Administration >> Software Sources", click "Other Software" tab, untick the mozilla-daily entries, click "Close". It will update. Then reinstall firefox with: sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox

Answer (score 2):

ubuntu: downgrade to firefox 3.6

`wget "http://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-3.6&os=linux&lang=en-US"`

`tar xvjf firefox-*.bz2`

`sudo cp -r firefox /usr/lib/firefox-3.6`

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox.old
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/firefox-3.6/firefox /usr/bin/firefox-3.6
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/firefox-3.6 /usr/bin/firefox
```

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu 11.04 you can easily install Firefox from the command line.
Get the `amd64.deb` packages from here :

Mozilla Firefox 3.6.24 on ubuntu 10.04 to 11.04 x86_64
http://www.crashrecovery.org/firefox/3.6.24+build2+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1/

installation : first remove all of your Firefox 5.0 stuff with `dpkg -r` or even
`dpkg --purge`, next install `firefox`, `firefox-branding` and `firefox-gnome-suppor`t :

`[acer30:root]:(~)# <b>dpkg -i firefox_3.6.24+build2+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1_amd64.deb firefox-branding_3.6.24+build2+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1_amd64.deb firefox-gnome-support_3.6.24+build2+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 0):

check out http://blog.troyastle.com/2011/06/downgrade-to-firefox-36-on-ubuntu-natty.html. Sometimes you need to do this if the owners of a website you need have put in code and/or features that are firefox version specific.