# Installing a downgraded version of Firefox 16 from PPA

Tags: apt, firefox, ppa

I'd like to fetch and install old FF16 instead of FF17 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS **server**.

Currently FF17 is default. FF17 is incompatible with Selenium 2.26 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600247/unable-to-run-selenium-suite-on-firefox-17

How one can install an old version of Firefox with apt-get? Can one pindown this version so that it is not automatically updated?

Also if there exists a static FF16 installation available it is a solution.

```
apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 17.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
  Candidate: 17.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 17.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 0
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.6.3+nobinonly-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me the issue was solved using the following steps:

1. download Firefox from Mozialla:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/16.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-16.0.tar.bz2`
   ```
2. for single-user installation:

   1. unpack the archive within my home directory:
      `mkdir -p ~/bin/firefox-16`
      `cd ~/bin/firefox-16`
      `tar -xjf ~/Downloads/firefox-16.0.tar.bz2`
   2. Create a symlink to my `~/bin` directory:
      `ln -s ~/bin/firefox-16/firefox ~/bin/firefox`
   3. I did that long time ago already, for you the step might be missing: open your `~/.profile` and make sure to have `~/bin` at the beginning of your `$PATH`:
      `# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists`
      `if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then`
      `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"`
      `fi`
3. For global installation, simply use the same steps as root, but replace the locations:

   - unpack to `/usr/local/bin/firefox-16`
   - symlink: `ln -s /usr/local/bin/firefox-16/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox`

For the global installation, no update of profiles should be required, as `/usr/local/bin` should already be in the `$PATH`. In both cases it is important this new path *precedes* `/usr/bin` (i.e. the new path should come *before* it), so the manually installed firefox is found first.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab an older Version from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/firefox.mirror/files/?source=navbar

And then you might go on like described here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/35756/112610

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Mozilla's FTP has older Firefox versions available:

http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/16.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/